# Sending emails using AngularJS

Tags: .net, angularjs, email

I am very new to AngularJS. I want to send emails. Is the server side code necessary to send emails if I am using AngularJS? How to send emails using AngularJS? I am a .NET guy. I am using Visual Studio 2012. Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Client-side, you can use a `mailto:` URL to open the user's email client. The user will have to actually send the mail, though. Will this do?

Comment: If you're trying to automatically send mails from within the browser without any user interaction,  you can stop here. It would be a severe security bug if that was allowed. You either need to use a server or let the user send that mail as @flup explained.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, automatically sending an email is server side code. But if you still want to send email using javascript alone try node.js and nodemailer.

https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer